# Why can't Preview export some TIFFs to PNG?

Tags: macos, preview

Some TIFFs can't be exported to PNG in Preview. What is preventing this and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the image is in [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK).

PNG does not support the CMYK color mode therefore Preview won't suggest it for the export.

Comment: So can I convert CMYK to RGB in Preview then?

Comment: This is not possible in preview directly. Maybe the script suggested on SuperUser might interest you : http://superuser.com/a/117489/95841